# Why is there no "scenes collection" for this flamethrower demonstration?

Tags: mantaflow

Here is a V2 flamethrower file that doesn't work for Blender V3, How do I find the scenes collection list? What other steps can I take to make it work? I only need to tweak the camera and change the meshes, I am lost.

https://www.blenderguru.com/s/Finished_flamethrower.blend

[image]

Comment: Suggest you start Blender then go to File > Open. Click the gear icon  In the top right corner of the file selector (or press 'N') to open the sidebar then uncheck 'Load UI'. Now select and open your Blend file. That will open it with the default layout and should show the outliner as normal.

Comment: or just press this button here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0FYH.png and choose "outliner". But honestly i would recommend watching some free blender UI tutorials how to use the UI because this is important and will teach you some nice tricks and shortcuts.